# Pandas Different Sampling Size

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random, sampling

Anyone can help me with pandas?

I have a set of data n= 50, how can I select random sample from the data if i required to randomly selected it based on different size.

For example:

1. a = From 50, i need to select 25
2. b = From 50, i need to select 5
3. c = Fom 50, i need to select 10
4. d = From 50, i need to select 2
5. e = From 50, i need to select 8

I used

```
a = df.sample(25)
```

how can i make sure, if i create b=df.sample(5) it is not a same sample with a,c,d,e?

Answer (score 1):

Try shuffling the dataframe using [sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html#pandas-dataframe-sample), then pulling slices with [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas-dataframe-iloc):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create DataFrame With Dummy Data
src_df = pd.DataFrame(np.linspace(150, 500, 50), columns=['Value'])

# Randomly Shuffle Data
shuffled = src_df.sample(frac=1)

# Number of Rows Per Group
rows_to_grab = [25, 5, 10, 2, 8]

# Make Sure Row Groups Add up to Total Number of Rows
assert sum(rows_to_grab) == len(shuffled)

dfs = []
start_index = 0
for rows in rows_to_grab:
    # Append Shuffled Rows to dfs
    dfs.append(shuffled.iloc[start_index: start_index + rows])
    start_index += rows

# Print Out
for header, df in zip("abcde", dfs):
    print(f'       {header}       ')
    print(df)
```

The groups could also be assigned manually:

```py
a = shuffled.iloc[:25]
b = shuffled.iloc[25:30]
c = shuffled.iloc[30:40]
d = shuffled.iloc[40:42]
e = shuffled.iloc[42:50]
```

Sample possible output of `e`:

```
       e       
         Value
13  242.857143
48  492.857143
28  350.000000
25  328.571429
39  428.571429
17  271.428571
41  442.857143
18  278.571429
```